# grails joda time plugin

Tags: grails, jodatime

I'm using joda time to deal with dates and times in my grails project (joda time plugin). Most of the time I want to bind dates from view or from json objects.
To setup default date formatter I need to add this line in config. groovy

```
jodatime.format.org.joda.time.LocalDate = 'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

So dates that come in this format, e.g. 23/03/2016 are bindable in my LocalDate, but sometimes for other formats my bind fail, e.g. 2016-03-23. It's a posibility to add multiple formats in config.groovy for a joda time date? Smth like this ?

```
jodatime.format.org.joda.time.LocalDate = ['dd/MM/yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd' ]
```

This code is not working, I get inspired from java.uti package

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['dd/MM/yyyy','MMddyyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"]
```